# Xamarin.android studio, a simple synthesizer app with AudioTrack using c# csharp - what is it in Java: samples[i] = (short) (amp*Math.sin(ph));?

Tags: c#, java, android, math, xamarin

Good day. I am currently making a music app for Android in Xamarin studio using csharp. First, I created a primitive synthesizer app in Java (in Eclipse) following this tutorial: [A simple synth in Android: step by step guide using the Java SDK](http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/a-simple-synth-in-android-step-by-step-guide-using-the-java-sdk/)

It works well with Java SDK. Now, I am doing the same in C# using Xamarin.android studio.

So, from the above tutorial, the sound synthesis loop in Java is as follows:

```
while(isRunning){

for(int i=0; i < buffsize; i++){ 
samples[i] = (short) (amp*Math.sin(ph));
ph += twopi*fr/sr;
}
audioTrack.write(samples, 0, buffsize);
}
```

However, I do not understand this line (namely the syntax):

```
samples[i] = (short) (amp*Math.sin(ph));
```

So I can't do the same in C# unless I know what exactly it does. F.e. why is there (short) before (amp*Math.sin(ph))?

I figured out that in C# this line will correspond to :

```
samples[i] = (short) (amp*System.Math.Sin(ph));
```

I would be very grateful if you could either explain it to me or point me to some documentation that I could read up.

Answer (score 0):

Re: Why is there a short before (amp*math...)?

I presume "samples" is an array of short integer values: Since System.Math.Sin() returns a double floating point number, you would have to truncate and cast the value to make it a short integer. The "(short)" keyword tells the compiler to do just that.

Comment: Thank you very much, Domin8urMind. Indeed, samples is an array of short integer values. And now it all makes sense! :)